# Determinar altura máxima de um titulo de coluna no Primefaces

Tags: css, css3, primefaces

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer o seguinte:

Preciso em uma `datatable` definir uma altura máxima de uma coluna. Porque tem algumas que o texto fica extenso demais e o valor da coluna é um Sim ou Não, assim o título fica demasiadamente grande. Então pensei na possibilidade de quebrar o titulo, mas com um altura máxima. Assim o texto ficaria com o tamanho que seria ideal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só para me certificar antes de avançar com alguma resposta: esta imagem exibe o resultado pretendido?

Comment: Não. Seria o que não quero, gostaria de limitar ao máximo de 3 linhas de altura. Problema que percebi que aí usar o onDemand do primefaces ele pode ficar todo quebrado, o título em relação ao conteúdo da coluna.

Comment: Antes mesmo de responder... Pelo que vejo uma solução passaria por aumentar a largura de tal forma que tivéssemos no máximo 3 linhas. E por outra, se forem colunas dinâmicas, aí a coisa pode complicar mais um pouco, entre tanto terias de limitar à uma altura fixa, uma largura considerável e um certo limite de caráteres. Minha opinião. O que achas?

Comment: Amigo o que falta do outro lado dessa mensagem é conhecimento, rs.  Mas é o seguinte eu consegui fazer isso aumentando em muito a largura da tabela estipulado um valor de porcentagem muito acima do dialog que eu uso para exibir, ai sim consegui controlar o tamanho das colunas problema é que o recurso da datatable onDemand ele as vezes da pau, vi outros usuários reclamando disso também.

Comment: Não entendi isso "Amigo o que falta do outro lado dessa mensagem é conhecimento, rs.", podias explicar @Macario1983?

Comment: Quando você diz limitar ao tamanho máximo de caracteres

Comment: Ham, ok! Então não há conhecimento sobre a quantidade máxima de carateres? Ok, se o assunto já foi resolvido, podias responder a própria questão mano.

Comment: Só para eu entender quando se fala em máximo de caracteres, seria preencher de teste um campo com o máximo que ele suporta e aí sim ajustar?

Comment: Bem, eu achei que poderia haver uma estimativa de um texto máximo para as colunas (ex: 90), e sabendo isso, ajustarias uma largura máxima (usando max-width do CSS) da coluna de tal forma que suportasse no máximo 3 linhas. Sei que seria uma forma agressiva de resolver, mas poderíamos considerar como última hipótese.

Comment: Hum, eu entendi que você teria algum algoritmo dinâmico que reconhece o conteúdo de uma célula e ajusta a largura

Comment: Hum, outra sugestão interessante! Acredito que seria menos grosseira que a que propus.

Comment: Problema é fazer isso

Comment: As colunas têm o atributo "width" e o mesmo poderia receber o vallor definido pelo método "determinaTamanho" que recebe como parâmetro o texto de cabeçalho. Depois seria saber apenas a relação de x carateres para y pixeis. que achas?

Comment: Pensei em algo do tipo achar uma multiplicação de pixel * caracteres.  Mas será que isso não deixaria lento a pagina?

Comment: Bem, lento não acredito, não seria a coisa mais eficiente do mundo, mais intuitivamente creio que não deixaria lenta (seria uma operação algébrica mui simples). Aconselho-te a experimentar na mesma.

Comment: Poderia postar o código atual de uma forma generalizada? Ajudaria e muito na elaboração de uma resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer o que você perguntou basta definir max-height no stilo da sua coluna definindo o tamanho máximo em pixels.

```
<p:column ... style="max-height: 50px" >
```

Mas no caso que você citou acima eu recomendaria colocar uma abreviação na linha do cabeçalho e na propriedade title colocaria o texto completo. Dessa forma quando o usuário passar o mouse em cima do cabeçalho irá aparecer o texto completo. Ex:

```
<h:outputText value="Pode alterar" title="Permissão para alterar os dados cadastrais do cliente" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar uma caixa de detalhes quando usuário passar o mouse por cima do nome da coluna. Quanto a formatação do nome da coluna em si, você pode escolher definir como linha única ou  com um limite do número de linhas que você quer que apareçam.

```
  <div class="box box1">
    <p class="text-box">
      Nome da coluna introduzido e abreviado em uma única linha.
    </p>
    <p class="detalies">
      Mais detalhes sobre o nome da coluna
    </p>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="box box2">
    <p class="text-box">
      Caso queira colocar um limite de mais de uma linha nome da coluna. Digamos 2 linhas.
    </p>
    <p class="detalies">
      Mais detalhes
    </p>
  </div>
```

```
.box{
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
}

.box .detalies{
  display:none;
}

.box:hover .detalies{
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: -100%;
  left: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(126,126,126, 0.2);
}

.box1 p {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.box2 p {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
```